# Invalid NUMBER Error in PLSQL block

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the following query which gives invalid number exception. If i just replace the date (06/10/2016 11:53:46 AM) with sysdate, it works fine.please let me know where am i wrong in this.

```
DECLARE
count NUMBER;
BEGIN
 SELECT COUNT(*) INTO count  FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE ID =123
 AND TO_CHAR('06/10/2016 11:53:46 AM','HH24:MI') > REJECTTIME;
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(count);
 END;
```

Comment: What is this block *supposed* to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confused.  `sysdate` is a date/time value, not a string.  If you want equivalent code, then use:

```
TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('06/10/2016 11:53:46 AM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'), 'HH24:MI') > REJECTTIME
```

That is, convert the value to a date and then to the string for the comparison.

You are getting the error because your string is not in a format compatible with the `'HH24:MI'` formatting code.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to convert the AM PM timeformat to a 24 hour format ? If thats what you want, you could try this..

```
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO count  FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE ID =123 and 
to_char(to_date('06/10/2016 11:53:46 AM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'),'HH24:MI') > REJECTTIME
```